# Moving specific Text from once cell in a range to another cell in a different range

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to move specific text (In this case the term "Low risk") from one column to another on the same sheet.

I have tried several variations of ".Cut" function in the Macro Developer, but none seem to work.

Comment: Set Rng = Range("A2:BH53", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In Rng
    If cell.Value = "Low risk " ( I want to move the contents reading "Low Risk:  to a different row/column) 
    cell.ClearContents
    End If
Next

End Sub

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with that code, instead of putting it in a comment? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood correctly the question, but to take a value  from a cell to another with vba use something like

```
    Worksheets("Name").Cells(rowNo, column2No).Value = Worksheets("Name").Cells(rowNo, column1No).Value
    Worksheets("Name").Cells(rowNo, column1No).clear
```

Hope it help you somehow

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim strValueToRemove As String, strString As String

    strValueToRemove = "Low Stock"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
         strString = .Range("A1").Value
        .Range("A1").Value = Replace(strString, strValueToRemove, "")
        .Range("B1").Value = strValueToRemove
    End With

End Sub
```

**Notes:**

`Replace` is case sensitive